# Creating our own aspects using custom annotations

Tags: java, annotations, aspects

I am new to Annotations and new to StackOverflow and this is my first question. I am trying to write custom annotations which will help me trace and log method executions.

For example:

```
class A
{

@Logthis

void methodA();

}
```

Here whenever the method `methodA()` is executed, I want to log to a file telling "we are entering the methodA in class A" and when methodA is over "we are exiting methodA in class A" something like this. We vil have a number of classes and methods.

I know that this can be done using AspectJ. I have done it by defining pointcuts and joinpoints. But I want to do it using custom annotations.

It will be very helpful if anyone can guide me as to how to go about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hiya, there's more to aspectj than just the annotations enabling call interception. Behind the aspectj annotations is functionality that enables method calls to be "intercepted" and inspected and call-outs to advice's to be made. This is actually done through compile time weaving in aspectj. So, your solution will probably need to use aspectj to manage the "interceptions". Bit of a sky-high overview but was concerned you may not have understood that(?)

Comment: Note that you can't just write your own annotations that extend aspectj annotations. Would be a solution otherwise, albeit a complex dependency to manage.

Comment: Hi wmorrison365, I have already used aspectj to achieve this using pointcuts and advice, but the requirement says i cannot import any external jar files or plugins, so it vil be like creating my own aspectj jar file and using it.

Comment: Oh, ok. If this is commercial then that's a bit of a backward stance but that's not your fault. If it's a project then it's pretty substantial. I guess the point of my comment is that there's more to the solution (or more to aspectj) than just putting in annotations, you need an engine to monitor code-flow/ execution and make decisions on each method call. Spring does this through run-time proxies, aspectj does it though compile time weaving. Perhaps see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-aopwork8/ for details on how aspectj works. It's old (aspectj 5/ 2005) but looks decent.

Comment: Either way, you need to be able to track the code execution flow and call into your aspects when some method matches. aspectj does this through compile-time weaving. I think spring does (or did) it through a run-time proxy to your object and introspection before calling #invoke on the real target object.

Comment: @wmorrison365  ya i found an example where they have another parser class which parses the classes and checks if they have any annotations, if present ,depending on annotation it does some work, but i feel its no more different than calling log function in whichever method we want. ex : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130653/custom-annotation-as-interceptor-for-a-method-logging , sorry since im new here , din know how to put this link , so im posting the whole link. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using AspectJ you do the following :-

Create an Aspect Class annotated with @Aspect

Annotation a method in the class with @Around and define the value to be execution on classes that you have annotated. You will also need to have enabled proxying of you classes by AspectJ.

```
@Aspect
public class LoggerAspect {

    @Around(value = "execution(@you.custom.Annotation * *(..))")
    public Object logMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable
    {
        // DO LOGGING HERE
    }

}
```

Comment: I cannot use any external jars or plugins to achieve this, "@Aspect" and "@Around" annotations can be used only after we add the aspectj plugin or similar to that , i want to do it without these external plugins. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Log4J. Here is a tutorial of it:

http://javakane.blogspot.fr/2012/07/automate-log4j-logging-with-aop-and.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying , i am already using log4j for logging , but i dunno how to make use of annotations to log messages whenever the method is executed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to *roll your own* aop framework. IMHO this is not a very good idea, a lot of work has gone into `AspectJ` and you would benefit greatly from using it. But I suspect you already know that :) It is strange that you can use NO external jars, that is rather stringent even for commercial software.

But if you really need to do it, you can probably learn from others. `AspectJ` is open source and there is nothing stopping you from reading through it and adapting it to you needs.

For limited requirements, it is probably not very complex either. You would need a [`java agent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) which can look at annotations on classes and methods as they are loaded and modify their bytecode to add logging. Again, there are excellent libraries out there that can aid this but alas you cannot use them.

Another option might be to use [jpda](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/). I have no experience with that, but I suspect it will have a significant impact on performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , ya aspectj is very useful , i already used tat to achieve my requirements. But ya i also need to achieve this without any external JARs. I vil definitely check out java agent and jpda , only need to do logging so i hope it wouldn be complex :)