# Android annotations with action

Tags: java, android, annotations

Hi i try to create new annotation with action:

**My annotation**

```
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface myCustomAnnotations{
    String errorMessage();
}
```

**My fucntion**

```
  @myCustomAnnotations(errorMessage = "error message")
    public void sendIssue() {
    }
```

**now i want to log the error message if someone call this method**

I search for ever for solution, so if you can help me, it will be awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any existed solutions for logging you can take a look at `AspectJ`.
With `AspectJ` you will be able to write an aspect which will be called after, before or around methods specified by your annotation. There are a lot of details, so it's better to see here for example http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

This won't be done simply by declaring custom annotation on methods. Annotations won't trigger automatically. If it were normal annotations then it could be triggered/executed by Annotation Processor at compile time. In your case, as you're using `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` that means annotation needs to be parsed at runtime manually. Have a good read on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12130885/2709580). Using the reflection, this is the way you can log your message.